# Tailwind CSS Responsive design not using properties at larger sizes

Tags: html, css, reactjs, tailwind-css, responsive

For default (mobile version - screen < 600px) I use this:

```
<div className="flex flex-col"/>
```

For larger screen sizes (screen > 600px) I don't want so use "flex-col" anymore.

How can I do this?

Comment: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/responsive-design follow `Customizing breakpoints` section.

Answer (score 0):

Use `sm:flex-col`

`sm` would be `> 640px`

```html
<div className="flex sm:flex-col"/>
```

This is mentioned in the Tailwind documentation:

[Flex - Tailwind](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/flex#breakpoints-and-media-queries)

[Customizing Screens (breakpoints) - Tailwind](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/screens)